# JAXP: How to dynamically resolve a Schema during XML parsing?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xsd, jaxp

Imagine a xml file which refers to a schema using `noNamespaceSchemaLocation`.

I'd like to resolve the value defined in `noNamespaceSchemaLocation` dynamically using some kind of resolving technique (like `ResourceResolver` for resolving schema includes) during parsing (default values in the schema have to be considered)

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that when you call `Validator.setResourceResolver()`, the LSResourceResolver you supply is used for this purpose (it is in the Saxon implementation of the JAXP interface, but you would need to run a test to check that it's also true of the Xerces implementation).